# Front door glass 1836

Tags: glass, front-door

The house was built in 1836 and the front door now has a kind of daisy (?) patterned glass - is this original or what would have been there?[image]

Comment: Is the door original?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: That glass is not from 1836, I concur with the answer it looks more like 1960s.  What would have been there?  You need to tell us where you are, show a picture of your entire house, and of neighbors' houses and of other houses like yours in your vicinity.  You need to look at historic books about your neighborhood.  This isn't the forum for all that.  Try Facebook groups like *Historic Home Renovations* and *Our Old House*

Comment: Many thanks for both answers - I suspected as much about the date. I thought the door might be original because the neighbouring house has a very similar door. Glass panels of any form might be recent additions, although there are also glass side lights on either side of the door

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no historian, but glass from the 1800s is known to be primitive and wavy.  The perfect flat glass we have today wasn't made until well into the 1900s.  The glass in your window is not only flat, but its patterned.  Truly old windows with decoration would have used techniques like stained glass windows with lead dividing lines.

I have a feeling this was from the 1960s or 1970s.  There was a lot of patterned glass in that time and more experimentation with glass design.